# Canvas does not work in Widget of durandal + typescript

Tags: knockout.js, typescript, durandal

I wrote a widget for a durandal + typescript project. The widget contains a canvas. But the canvas only show once. The other html elements work good-they show the same times I call widget.

The following is widget view file:

```
<section class="leftbarchart" data-bind="foreach: { data: settings.items }">
    <canvas width="330" height="72"></canvas>
    <div class="text-scale">
      <div style="float: left;width:50px;" data-bind="text: $data[Object.keys($data)[0]].labels[0]"></div>
      <div style="float: right;width:50px;text-align: right;" data-bind="text: $data[Object.keys($data)[0]].labels[2]"></div>
      <div style="text-align: center" data-bind="text: $data[Object.keys($data)[0]].labels[1]"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The following is part of viewmodel

```
private canvas :HTMLCanvasElement;
private ctx :CanvasRenderingContext2D ;

public attached(element:HTMLElement){
        this.canvas = element.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[6];//<HTMLCanvasElement>$('canvas', element)[0];//
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        this.drawLine(this.ctx, this.origin[0], this.origin[1], this.origin[0] + this.width, this.origin[1]);
        this.drawLine(this.ctx, this.origin[0], this.origin[1] + this.height, this.origin[0] + this.width, this.origin[1] + this.height);

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            this.drawLine(this.ctx, this.origin[0] + this.unitWidth * 2 + this.unitWidth * i, this.origin[1], this.origin[0] + this.unitWidth * 2 + this.unitWidth * i, this.origin[1] + this.height, [1.5]);
        }

        this.drawCurrentBar(this.ctx, 0.7);
        this.drawLastBar(this.ctx, 0.9);
        this.wrapText(this.ctx, "Business Performance", 20, 40, 50, 20);
    }
```

Please pay attention to

```
this.canvas = element.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[6];
```

If I change the index to [0], it only show 1st widget's canvas. It it is [6], only show 7th widget's canvas. 
How to let every widget show canvas?

Comment: this is a difficult question to answer because its a bit complicated. its hard to know whats going on here. if you have a widget, you should be able to bind it independently in various places. then, each widget will have only one child canvas. thats the goal

Comment: Are you returning a constructor function in the viewModel of your widget?  If not, then you have a singleton viewModel on your hands, and that would cause the canvas (or, actually, the logic *behind* the canvas) to be shared.  Could you post your entire viewModel, but not the TypeScript, the JavaScript that gets emitted?

Comment: Perhaps invalid but : use a loop?